# Excel - concatenated string has double quotes when a / (slash) is in the string

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I currently have several columns of data in excel 2010.
e.g.

```
       A      |      B      |        C
1|     Dave   |     101     |     Carpenter
2|    Chris   |  10/01/2010 |     Brick layer
```

I am concatenating the cells for each row to build a SQL query.

```
=Concatenate("Insert Into myTable Values ('", A1, "', '", B1, "', '", C1, "';"")
=Concatenate("Insert Into myTable Values ('", A2, "', '", B2, "', '", C2, "';"")
```

It works fine until I get to a row where column B has a value (not always a date) with a slash (/) in it. When this happens I end up with the output as double ""
e.g.

```
""Insert Into mytable Vales ('Chris', '10/01/2010', 'Bricklayer"";"
```

When I a the extra cells to concatenate the DoCmd.RunSQL part it ends up:

```
"DoCmd.RunSQL (""Insert....
I don't need the first or second "
```

For rows with no slash (/) it works fine. Is there a way to remove the extra " in this instance?

I am using this to build DoCmd.RunSQL strings for VBA in ms Access to add a large number of rows to a table.

Comment: Can you clarify the expected output? In the first row, do you expect output of `Insert Into myTable Values ('Dave', '101', 'Carpenter';"`?  A big guess, but do you want this instead: `=CONCATENATE("""Insert Into myTable Values ('",A1,"', '",B1,"', '",C1,"');""")`?

Answer (score 0):

I could insert successfully into my database using the formula below. Please just make sure to convert the dates into date format before inserting it, if you want to use this field properly.

`="insert into my table values ("&"'"&A2&"'"&","&"'"&B2&"'"&","&"'"&C2&"'"&")"&";"`.